# Making a bot to fill out a Troops.ai dialog to update a salesforce record, how to have my bot fill out troops dialog?

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api, botkit

I am trying to make a slack bot that interacts with the  [Troops](https://troops.ai/)  application. Right now, a team is receiving a message and manually inputting a form into salesforce, and I think it would be much easier, efficient, and accurate to have a computer program do it. For security and privacy reasons, the salesforce administrators want me to try and use troops, which allows me to edit the form, so the idea is to call a certain form, update it with information whenever we get it in the slack, then have salesforce copy and save the form as a new one.

My question is can I have my slack bot press two salesforce buttons and input one line of text into a troops message? If yes, what is the best way to go about this? Currently I have some code written up using the edit message feature, but am unsure if editing the message will actually change anything or submit the form... I am also using [BotKit](https://botkit.ai/)  as a base if that changes anything or makes this easier or harder.

Here is the edit message code I have now that is not finished, but I feel like won't work...

[image: Current Code screenshot]

If there is a better way to do this I am open to hearing ideas as well.

Thanks for the help in advance

Edit: Or if anyone knows if bots can interact with interactive messages or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, it is not possible to interact with Slack dialogs from an external API.